# Regex Replace Matches All instead of single

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to understand Regex Replace Method.  I wrote a function that should insert a space before the first capital letter that is not preceded by a capital letter.

```
var tmpDisplay = Regex.Replace(name, "([^A-Z ])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

When I run this it replaces all of the capital letters that are not preceded by a capital letter.

I Checked MSDN and it doesn't seem to mention that regex replaces act global on the string instead of matching just the first case.

How can I only replace a single value?  Could anyone provide the documentation about this issue?

Comment: You need to declare a regex object and use the regex object instance to replace just once.

Comment: What's the content of `name` ?

Comment: @Thomas its just your input  example "TestNameDTO"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The static `Regex.Replace` method has no max occurrences argument, but the class instance has:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"([^A-Z ])([A-Z])");
Console.WriteLine(rx.Replace("NamePeteParker", "$1 $2", 1)); // Replace just once
                                                       ^^
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/k5SmlN)

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e47f3dkc(v=vs.90).aspx):

> `Regex.Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator, Int32)`
>   Within a specified input string, replaces a **specified maximum number of strings** that match a regular expression pattern with a string returned by a MatchEvaluator delegate.

Comment: Thank you, I was so confused on why that was working!